# get image as jpeg format from excel in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, jpeg

how to read image in cell of the excel sheet. This sheet contain .jpeg formated images. I want as they are means in jpeg format. i am using asp.net and c# for this. please guide.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend reading this tutorial:

- [Reading Image from Excel file using C# .Net](http://joymonscode.blogspot.com/2009/01/reading-image-from-excel-file.html)

Comment: Yes, i make a code according this article. but i  am facing new problem. how to get original name of image. please don't suggest Picture.Name property. this is giving me "Picture1" like this names. i need originals///how can i get ??

Comment: Also how to know is R2C1 contain image or null??